# In UICollectionView why do we have dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, uicollectionview

instead of the normal

```
dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier
```

This `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` requires us to register stuffs. Which is annoying.

The question does not ask why we bother dequeing cell at all. I know why. This question ask why we do not dequeue UICollectionView the way we dequeue UITableView

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "register stuffs". But it is annoying. With `UITableView`, I find it very convenient to dequeue an extra cell out of the storyboard and use it for height calculations. As far as I know, this can't be done with `UICollectionView` because of the need to provide a valid `NSIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, a collection view's data source should generally reuse `UICollectionViewCell` objects when it assigns cells to items in its `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. A collection view maintains a queue or list of `UICollectionView` objects that the data source has marked for reuse.

Comment: Yes just like in UITableView. However, in UITableView we uses dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, not dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath

Comment: This is an old approach. Apple recommends to use dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: for table views in performance reasons.

Comment: Apple says so. Anyway you don't have any alternatives for UICollectionView.

Comment: And what's Apple consideration?

Comment: You should register class or nib for cell. And use dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath in collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Do you see any other solutions?